# Student Struct Troubles

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, struct

I am learning `structs` and I am still little confused about them and what they do. The code I have is my attempt of it and I keep getting segmentation faults. My goal for the main is to ask the user to see how many students they want to add, and each information for name and score while calling a function. I also want to print the data array off to the user.

- For the `loadStudentData()` function, I want to store the `newName` and `NewScore` into the `newStudent` Structure.
- For `printStudentData()` I want to print data for a single student
- Then for the `printStudentArray()` I want to call `printStudentData()` function on each member for the students array.

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define STUDENT_NAME_LENGTH 20

typedef struct{
char* name;
int score;
}Student;

void loadStudentData(Student *newStudent,char* newName,int newScore);
int printStudentData(Student student);
void printStudentArray(Student* students, int numStudents);


/*
 *
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
int numberOfStudents;
Student *newStudent;
char* newName;
int newScore;
int student;


Student students[numberOfStudents];

printf("how many students: ");
scanf("%d", &numberOfStudents);


    loadStudentData(newStudent, newName, newScore);

    printStudentArray(students, numberOfStudents);


  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void loadStudentData( Student *newStudent, char* newName, int newScore){
 int i;
    char *studentName = (char *) malloc(STUDENT_NAME_LENGTH *  sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s", studentName);
    newStudent->name = studentName;

    int nScore;
    scanf("%d", &nScore);
    newStudent[i].score = newScore;
  }
 int printStudentData(Student student){

int i;

    printf("Student name\t%s\n",) ;
    printf("Student score\t%d\n",);

     }



 void printStudentArray(Student* students, int numStudents){
 int i;
for (i = 0; i < numStudents; i++) {
    printf("Student name\t%s\n", students[i].name);

    printf("Student score\t%d\n", students[i].score);
   } 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

- **Point 1:** `Student students[numberOfStudents];` is invalid, as `numberOfStudents` is uninitialized.
- **Point 2:** In your code, you're calling `printStudentArray()` before populating `student` itself.

  This function tries to access the uninitialized memory at `name` variable which causes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
- **Point 3:** In your `loadStudentData()` function, you're using `i` uninitialized . Again UB.

That said,

1. Always check for success of `malloc()` before using the retuned pointer.
2. Please [do not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: student[numberofstudents], will never work, cos numberofstudents needs to be determined at compile time. The OP needs to malloc/calloc the student array and subsequently free it before exit.

Comment: @rhubarbdog is it? I'm interested. Please tell me how. (FWIW, I referred [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)). And is that the reason for the downvote? :-)

Comment: C doesn't have variable length arrays like that wiki discusses. At present all that statement will do is create a fixed length array of zero elements, hence you can store nothing. In c you either measure, allocate the space use it and free it. Or start with something, start populating growing (realloc) and populating, make it smaller if required, use then and finally when done free. I cannot stress you must free all memory you acquire via calloc,malloc or realloc otherwise it's a memory leak

Comment: `C doesn't have variable length arrays like that wiki discusses.`.. did you consider `C99` also? :-)

Comment: C is the language. Things like C99 and C11 are standards. Point 4...  Never cast the address returned by malloc, look it up on SO for the rationale

Comment: @rhubarbdog ok then, **(1)** what are standards for, if not establishing the specifications for language? **(2)** did you miss the last line of my answer?

Comment: Sorry, did miss the last line of your post, my bad. I know why I never considered that tweak to C. Ages ago when I was new to C after completing my first major program. I did quite a lot of reading man pages and similar relating to C etc. That's when I learned of this new kinda cool feature of C99. My introduction to this concept was don't use in production code because... I don't remember the rationale so subsequently have never considered it a language feature. I had the opportunity to start using c over 20 years ago, so come from a cleaner 3GL background I don't use long jump, or continue

Comment: They produce unprovable code. Avoid goto except how it's used in kernel standard programing. Goto is also unprovable, but limitations of c mean this is best practice and I can construct a proof for such code. Consider this, prototype struct bar foo(int arg); is perfectly valid to return a structure. But again rationale forgotten, K & R stated best practice is prototype void foo(struct bar *return_value, int arg); having the caller supply the storage for return value *ALWAYS* works. C11 formally revoked variable length arrays. It's now 15, so C11 is probably the standard to aim at.

Comment: sorry for my verbose reposted comments. I have trouble with the app on my phone. And yes it  is rhubarbdog, I use this name on many forums it's not an anonymous alias to hide behind. ((normal face))

Answer (score 0):

You call `printStudentArray` before you actually initialize the array of structures. That means all the data in the array will be *indeterminate* and using it in any way except to initialize it will lead to *undefined behavior* (which is a common cause of crashes).

More specifically, the problem is probably when you try to print the name, as the `name` pointer could point *anywhere*.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to not allocate the structs you are creating. Be aware that when you declare a variable such as `Student *newStudent;` you first have to **allocate** it. Because thus far, you have only declared a variable that holds a **pointer** to a `Student` struct, but this pointer points to nowhere. So use the malloc function everywhere you expect a valid pointer:

`newStudent = malloc(sizeof(newStudent));`